# How does Angular named (secondary) route works?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

Passing name route from router module seems not working. It just can navigate to actual route, but can't pass named route.

Here is my code snippet

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "products", component: ProductListComponent },
  { path: "product/:id", component: ProductDetailComponent },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/products(primary:products, sideBar:prod)',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: "products",
    component: ProductListSidebarComponent,
    outlet: "sidebar",
  },
  {
    path: "prod",
    component: TestComponent,
    outlet: "sidebar"
  }
];
```

I want to access this path (http://localhost:4200/products(sidebar:prod) ) from router module. But It always navigate to http://localhost:4200/products

How can I access to  http://localhost:4200/products(sidebar:prod) from router module.

router teamplte:

```
    <div >
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div>   
      <router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

Comment: `redirectTo: '/products(sidebar:prod)',` case sensitive and your primary outlet is decided by base path

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. just typo ..